# How can I tell if a Rust library is deprecated?

Tags: rust, deprecated

I am looking for a Rust library to parse dates and I found [the documentation for `time`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/time/time/index.html) which looks official.

I wanted to report a bug so I went to [the Crates.io page](https://crates.io/crates/time), which led me to the [Github repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/time) which sneakily redirected to the [rust-deprecated Github account](https://github.com/rust-lang-deprecated/time).

Is this library deprecated or not? How can I find out? There's no indication in the documentation or the code.

Comment: Asking on IRC seems like the most straightforward approach

Comment: I disagree. I can't do that for every library I'm using, and I would have to keep asking to check.

Comment: @Joe what other languages do you use that clearly indicate that a library is deprecated? Maybe there's something that Rust / Cargo can copy.

Comment: There are deprecation decorators in all kinds of of languages, e.g. Java and Python. I know these apply to functions rather than whole packages but it's easy to see in the documentation e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html?highlight=urllib#urllib.urlopen .  And PEP4 is relevant reading https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0004/ Steve's answer about what deprecation means in Rust was useful.

Comment: Sometimes a crate gains deprecated status in the security advisory DB maintained by the Rust team - https://github.com/rustsec/advisory-db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem here is that libraries often become deprecated because the maintainer doesn't have time. So the person who has the power to say "deprecated" also isn't in the position to do it.

The next release of Rust (1.9) will contain a "deprecated" attribute, which would allow someone to mark any part of an API as deprecated, and I guess it could be applied to a whole crate too.

That said, for "time", "deprecated" has a very specific meaning: it's a crate that was almost official, but is not any more, and has not had a new maintainer yet. If anyone wants to take over maintenance, they can request it, and it will be given to them. This only applies to crates that are in the rust-lang-nursery organization, and even that is a bit of history. In the future, I doubt many crates will end up "deprecated" in this way.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't expect Rust, being comparatively new, to have the same kind of stability as established languages like Python. Very good to know what deprecation means in the Rust ecosystem. I feel less bad about using the time library. It will be interesting to see if packages like for example time are truly 'deprecated' for the meaning of that attribute and will have this it applied or not.

Comment: Absolutely! For more context, here's how this works: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1242-rust-lang-crates.md